# Finder not searching files in ~/Library and /Library

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, spotlight, search

I am using a Macbook Air with macOS High Sierra.

When I install a third party application and later delete it, I have to remove files stored by it in Application Support, Preferences etc. in `~/Library`. I have to manually look up and delete files containing the name of the third party app (eg. com.EaseUsMobiMover installed by MobiMover).

Why doesn't Finder show these files when I search for them? And how do I make Finder search for all files containing the name of the app like com.abc for the app "abc"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to include "System Files" in your criteria to search places like the user Library.

[image: ![enter image description here]

To do so, open a search window in Finder <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, click on "*Kind*" and select "*Other*" and scroll down to "*System Files*".  Tick the box under "*In Menu*" for easier access in the future by including it in the search menu.
(You can also specify hidden files here, with the "*File invisible*" attribute)

[image]
[image]

You can also save those search criteria and add them to the Finder sidebar for quick access.

[image]

If the above does not yield the desired results, a [rebuild of the Spotlight index](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201716) might be required.

Comment: This is a great elaborate answer. It worked. I did not need to rebuild the Spotlight index.

Comment: But I still can't search the files in iCloud Drive.

Comment: @Bagusflyer iCloud Drive should be freely searchable.  It's more likely that this is a problem with Spotlight.  Re-indexing, deleting the old Spotlight store and whatever other troubleshooting options there are, seem more likely to get around it.

Comment: @Bagusflyer Posing the question to the community, adding all the troubleshooting you have tried and some details of your setup (OS, etc.), might be a better way to approach the problem.  Tucking it into a comment here most likely just results in the issue being overlooked.

Comment: @Redarm I tried re-indexing Spotlight by removing/adding volume to it and also by a command line command. Both are not working. My OS is venture. My home folder ~ is in an external volume. Not sure if this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Bagusflyer "My home folder ~ is in an external volume" That could be an issue.  Frankly I don't know.  I can search the mobile documents folder on an external drive, but I've never had my home folder on one.  That's out of my depth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* Finder will not search hidden & System folders, but it won't.

The simplest workaround is to use something like [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) - freeware - which will search anywhere you tell it.