# Finder excludes search results from Application Support folders

Tags: macos, finder, sonoma

For example, I am trying to search for a folder `chrome` under `/Users/userName/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/giiofe2i.default-release-1/chrome` and it does find it.

But when I move the search option to **This Mac** it does not show up. I tried re-indexing but I got the same results.

Does this mean Finder excludes certain folders by design? I am on the latest Sonoma 14.2.1

Comment: Yes, "system files" (and the home library is counted as such) are not included by default. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326573/49869